# Why anchors' position doesn't change after ARKit reconciling the recorded world map with the current environment?

Tags: arkit, world-map

Environment: ARKit 2.0, iPhone X, iOS 12.1

While running an `ARSeesion` at the `ARWorldMappingStatusMapped` state,

1. A few custom anchors at specified positions (**#A**) were added to the world map via `ARSession.AddAnchor`.
2. The world map was saved to a file.

Then **close** the app and restart the `ARSession`,

1. *configuration* Loaded the saved world map and assigned it to [`ARKitWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration.initialWorldMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2968180-initialworldmap?language=objc)
2. *run option* reset tracking and remove existing anchors
3. Then restart the session by calling [`ARSession.runWithConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-runwithconfiguration?language=objc) with the *configuration* and *run option* above.
4. When the state of `ARSession` indicates that it has reconciled the recorded world map with the current environment, read the positions of anchors (**#B**) from `ARWorldMap.anchors`.

But I found that positions of read anchors (**#B**) are not changed compared to positions when they were saved (**#A**). **That's incorrect. Why?**

Because the initial position of the phone is the position of coordinate origin. And the app was once closed and the phone was moved to another place. So the position of coordinate origin changed after restarting the `ARSeesion`. Then `ARSession` should also reconcile the positions of `ARAnchors` saved in the world map to proper places, thus the positions of `ARAnchors` should have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. The initial session, whose `initialWorldMap` is `nil` and run option is `0`, started **after** I restarted the session for reconciling. So it conflicted with the reconciling session. Which cancels reconciling. Thus the positions of loaded anchors will not change because they are unknown to the `ARSession`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`initialWorldMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2968180-initialworldmap?language=objc) documentation:

> If successful, the tracking state becomes ARCamera.TrackingState.normal after a short time, *indicating that the current world coordinate system* and anchors *match those from the recorded world map*.

The position of those anchors should be the same, however the origin of the world coordinate system should change after relocalization.

Comment: Thanks. But I think if the origin of the world coordinate changes, the position of an anchor should also change (exactly offset by the world coordinate difference). Otherwise the anchor will not be located at the correct position.

Comment: All positions are relative to the word coordinate system